# Cannot figure how loop is placed

Tags: c++

I cant figure this out...

When amount == 0, I want the program to exit, but if I dont and complete the whole process, I want the initial question to be asked again. It's crashing right now, when I enter 0. I cant use if statements, only loops.

```
main()
{
      int amount = 1;
      while(amount != 0)
      {
      cout <<"How many numbers do you wish to average? ";
      cin >> amount;
      int avg = 0, sum = 0;

            for (int lim = 0; lim < amount; lim++)
            {             
                cout <<"Enter a value (If multiple, one at a time)"<< endl;
                sum = sumNums(sum);
            }

            avg = sum / amount;
            displaySum (sum, avg);

      }
}

int sumNums (int sum)
{
    int number = 0;
    cin >> number;
    sum = sum + number;
    return sum;   
}

void displaySum (int sum, int avg)
{
     cout <<"The sum is "<< sum <<" and the average is "<< avg << endl;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following, although you may want to add in a prompt which asks the user to add an amount above zero.

```
int amount = 1;
while(true){
  do{
     while(amount==0) count << "ERROR: Enter a number greater than 0" << endl;
     cout <<"How many numbers do you wish to average?";
     cin >> amount;
  }while(amount == 0);
  int avg = 0, sum = 0;

        for (int lim = 0; lim < amount; lim++)
        {    
            do{
               cout <<"Enter value" << lim+1 << "/" << amount << endl;
               sum = sumNums(sum);
            }while(sum==0);
        }

        avg = sum / amount;
        displaySum (sum, avg);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
avg = sum / amount;
```

This line crashes when amount == 0, you  need to protect it with an if statement.

Comment: if you dont mind some minor inefficiency, you could just move it into the for loop. Alternatively, you could test for amount==0 after the cin>>amount, and then break/return/exit as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You're dividing by zero.
This crashes the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (amount == 0)
    break;
```

Place this just after reading the amount, it will both force the loop to end, and avoid the division by 0.

<s>Without if, once again after getting amount:</s>

```
while (amount == 0)
    break;
```

Edit:

Wait this one doesn't work, you will only get outside the test loop, You should use `return 0` instead, to exit the program.

Comment: The OP says he can't use if statements (presumably homework limitation)

Comment: That's what I get for not correctly reading the question. Although, this limitation is a bit useless, you can just replace an `if (test)` with a `while (test) ... break; `

Comment: you're right, this one doesn't work either. Damn, I need to check a bit more what I do.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too hard.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumNums(int sum);
void displaySum(int sum, int avg);

main()
{
      int amount = 1;
      for (;;)
      {
      cout <<"How many numbers do you wish to average? ";
      cin >> amount;
    **while (amount == 0) return 0;** // use this to halt execution

    **while (amount != 0){**
      int avg = 0, sum = 0;

            for (int lim = 0; lim < amount; lim++)
            {             
                cout <<"Enter a value (If multiple, one at a time)"<< endl;
                sum = sumNums(sum);
            }

            avg = sum / amount;
            displaySum (sum, avg);
        amount=0;
    }
      }
}

int sumNums (int sum)
{
    int number = 0;
    cin >> number;
    sum = sum + number;
    return sum;   
}

void displaySum (int sum, int avg)
{
     cout <<"The sum is "<< sum <<" and the average is "<< avg << endl;     
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of a cheat. I'm sure the intent of the assignment is to _not require_ these conditional checks, by forming the loops more cleverly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for your comment, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sumNums (int);
void displaySum (int, int);

int main()
{
  int amount = 1;
  cout <<"How many numbers do you wish to average? ";
  cin>>amount;
  while(amount != 0)
  {

  int avg = 0, sum = 0;

        for (int lim = 0; lim < amount; lim++)
        {             
            cout <<"Enter a value (If multiple, one at a time)"<< endl;
            sum = sumNums(sum);
        }

        avg = sum / amount;
        displaySum (sum, avg);
        cout <<"How many numbers do you wish to average? ";
        cin >> amount;

  }
}

int sumNums (int sum)
{
    int number = 0;
    cin >> number;
    sum = sum + number;
    return sum;   
     }

void displaySum (int sum, int avg)
{
     cout <<"The sum is "<< sum <<" and the average is "<< avg << endl;     
}
```